# Виды параметров функций в С#. Что такое params и с чем его едят?

Tags: c#, методы

Чем отличается параметр методов/функций params от параметров по ссылке?
Почему их выделяют в отдельную группу, если params вызывает массив, который в свою очередь является ссылочным типом данных? Когда возникает необходимость использовать params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если сравнивать params и обычный массив, то разницы со стороны рантайма никакой, они оба массивы и оба ссылочные типы. Слово `params` помогает компилятору понимать как можно вызывать методы, если это обычный массив, то программист должен сам его создавать/передавать, тогда как для params компилятор это сделает сам (т.е. по факту это синтаксический сахар). Используют его просто для удобства программиста (там где подразумевается, что метод может/должен принимать переменное количество параметров).

Это все можно увидеть на [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTAAhgRgOwFgBQBvLD9LIBsSALAgLICGYAdgBQoAMA2gLoJUBOA5gM4BKPAVyYC4zsnq0ApgHd2CbAmQAaBHHUBmBAF8BAbmETOceqXUBWdUUPG9WeyhIxyVKXWCKqQsSMd++LoB4s5kpvQADtxUALZ8CJ7evuKi9sGYukA==):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        a1(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        a2(4, 5, 6);
    }
    static void a1(int[] a) { }
    static void a2(params int[] a) { }
}
```

Созданы два метода, один обычный, другой с params. И сравнить какой IL-код (если не понятен il, можно переключить на c#) будет генерироваться для методов и их вызовов, все будет одинаково, за исключением того, что params, будет помечет атрибутом `ParamArrayAttribute`, по которому компилятор и будет понимать, можно ли передавать список параметров переменной длинны.